# How to use a PHP-generated image inside the FFMPEG?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that generates an image. So the result of the following code would be an image shown in the browser:

```
<?php
require_once('generateImg.php');`
```

Now I need to use that generated image instead of `img.jpeg` in the following command:

```
// This command successfully generates `output.mp4` file
exec('ffmpeg  -loop 1 -t 1 -i img.jpeg -i audio.mp3  -f flv -vf  scale=640:ih*640/iw -shortest output.mp4');
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
ob_start();
require_once('generateImg.php');
$img = ob_get_clean();

exec("ffmpeg  -loop 1 -t 1 -i $img -i audio.mp3  -f flv -vf  scale=640:ih*640/iw -shortest output.mp4");
```

But it doesn't generate the output.mp4 file. Any idea how can I do that?

---

Here's the content of `generateImg.php` file:

```
<?php

$image = imagecreate(500, 300);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 153, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagestring($image, 5, 180, 100,  "GeeksforGeeks", $text_color);
imagestring($image, 3, 160, 120,  "A computer science portal", $text_color);

header("Content-Type: image/png");

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: You can go this way. What does `$img` contain? The image or the path & filename? What's the output to see eventual error message?

Comment: @MarkusZeller The content of `generateImg.php` added

Comment: That is the problem. You need to save it as a local file and give the path/filename to ffmpeg.

Comment: Oh @MarkusZeller .. That's what I was worried to hear :-) .. Since the resource of the server that I use is weak, I cannot store all images on the server.

Comment: Well you could always delete the image after you've included it in the mp4 file. But honestly unless your image is huge, then surely the storage of that isn't going to be a problem compared to the storage space occupied by the video files?

Comment: @ADyson Well, I'm trying to not store anything, I want to generate the image, and the mp4 file when the user request for it.

Comment: I see. But that's the way ffmeg works at least - it requires the name of an image file as input. So save the image, use it in the ffmpeg command, and then delete it immediately afterwards.

Comment: Ah ok @ADyson Thanks for your comment .. As another question, do you know is there any approach to not save the final video using ffmeg on the storage and just show it to the user?

Comment: Since you're executing a command-line process to produce the video I would expect not - it knows nothing about your web context. Again though you could delete the file after you've finished with it. (That might need to be done as a background process at a later time, so that the user definitely has time to download it first).

Comment: I see, got it, thx @ADyson

Comment: You could use *nix piping to do it without a filesave `wget https://localhost/generateImg.php | ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i pipe:0 -i audio.mp3 -f flv -vf scale=640:ih*640/iw -shortest output.mp4`. But, I would recommend saving in a file and delete it afterwards like @ADyson said, already.